# Show existence of a continuous function with certain properties

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $C(X)$ the commutative algebra of continuous complex-valued functions endowed with the maximum-norm.

Let $J\subset C(X)$ be an ideal and $g\in J$. Let $0<\epsilon <1$. Show there exists a $u\in J $ such that $u = 1$ on the set $\{|g(x)|\geq 1\}$ and $u=0$ on $\{|g(x)|\leq \epsilon \}$ and $0\leq u(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in X$.

The existence of such continuous $u\in C(X)$ is just an applications of Urysohn's lemma. But to show there exists such $u\in J$ I can't yet figure out.

Since $J$ is an ideal, it would be enough to show that there exists a $f\in C(X)$ such that $fg=u$. This would mean that $f=1/g$ on $\{|g(x)|\geq 1\}$ and $f=0$ on $\{0<|g(x)|\leq \epsilon\}$.

But I don't see why such $f$ would be continuous. Any ideas?

Comment: $f$ would not have to be $0$ on $\{0 < \lvert g\rvert < 1\}$. It would have to be nonzero on a considerable part of that set.

Comment: Why? How can otherwise $f(x)g(x)= u(x)=0$ hold on the set $\{0<|g(x)|<1\}$ if $f(x)\neq 0$? Maybe I am confusing..i mean the set $\{x\in X: 0<|g(x)|<1\}$.

Comment: Because you don't have $u = 0$ on $\{ 0 < \lvert g\rvert < 1\}$. You have $u=0$ on $\{\lvert g(x)\rvert \leqslant\varepsilon\}$. For some $0 < \varepsilon < 1$.

Comment: Ha, yes ofcourse, i was confused indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the desired $u$ by Urysohn's lemma. Now define $U_1 = \{x : \lvert g(x)\rvert > \varepsilon/3\}$ and $U_2 = \{ x : \lvert g(x)\rvert < 2\varepsilon/3\}$. By the continuity of $g$, both $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open, and since $2\varepsilon/3 > \varepsilon/3$, we have $X = U_1 \cup U_2$. Then define

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{u(x)}{g(x)} &, x\in U_1\\ 0 &, x\in U_2. \end{cases}$$

$f$ is well-defined because on $U_1\cap U_2$, we have $u \equiv 0$.

Evidently $f$ is continuous on $U_2$, and on $U_1$, it is also continuous, as the quotient of two continuous functions, where the denominator doesn't vanish.
Hence $f$ is continuous on all of $X$.

Comment: Great, that's nice. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer is there a reason for mentioning explicitly that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open?

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck Yes. In general, if you have $X = A \cup B$ and $f\colon X \to Y$, you can't conclude the continuity of $f$ from the continuity of the restrictions $f\lvert_A$ and $f\lvert_B$. If you have (arbitrarily many) $U_\iota$ open with $X = \bigcup U_\iota$, then the continuity of $f$ follows from the continuity of $f\lvert_{U_\iota}$ for all $\iota$. You can also conclude the continuity of $f$ from the continuity of $f\lvert_{F_k}$ for all $k$ when you have $X = \bigcup_{k=1}^n F_k$ as a union of finitely many closed subspaces.